# Mysql query not using key as expected

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Given the following table why is my EXPLAIN saying it is not using any key (Specifically the `tag_pos_nr` key?

```
CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` mediumtext DEFAULT '0',
  `name` mediumtext DEFAULT 'John Doe',
  `pos` mediumtext DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` mediumtext DEFAULT '',
  `nr` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag_pos_nr` (`tag`(20),`pos`(20),`nr`),
  KEY `tag` (`tag`(20))
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id from my_tbl WHERE tag LIKE '%191223%' AND pos='pos1' AND nr=1;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | my_tbl  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 14238 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: `WHERE tag LIKE '%191223%'` The wildcard at the front of the string means this query is not sargable

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable

Comment: The index `tag` is redundant in your table definition. See what is [index prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_index_prefix). Your query can use an index if the `tag_pos_nr` is created with the columns in different _order_. For example,  `KEY tag_pos_nr(pos(20), nr, tag(20)) `,or `KEY tag_pos_nr(nr, pos(20), tag(20))`.

Answer (score 1):

- Prefixing (eg `tag(20)`) is virtually useless.  I don't think I have ever seen two prefixes being useful in a composite index as in your `tag_pos_nr`.
- `LIKE '%...'` cannot use the index (except for "covering"; see below).
- The best that can be done with *that* schema for `WHERE tag LIKE '%191223%' AND pos='pos1' AND nr=1` is

  ```
    INDEX(nr)
  ```

  or maybe

  ```
    INDEX(nr, pos(20))
  ```
- The order of the clauses in `WHERE` does not matter (the Optimizer will rearrange them if it sees fit); the order in the `INDEX` *does* matter.
- If tag, name, and/or pos are never very big, change to `VARCHAR(...)` and drop the prefixing in the `INDEXes`.
- `INDEX(a)` is redundant when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.
- A "Covering" index is one that contains *all* the columns that are used *anywhere* in the query.  Note:  prefixing does not allow for "covering" since part of the column is missing from the index.